# How to create special matrices of the following forms

Tags: matrix

How can I create:

Matrix 1:

[image]

Matrix2:

[image]

Matrix 3:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a general pattern for these matrices?

Comment: @J.M.: No, I do not. Matrix 1 is as general as it can get. The other matrices are quite specific in terms of x's and y's. I have a large matrix and extracted the index (position) numbers of each x's, y's etc.  Piece-wise multiplication of a `1` matrix with a vector may do the job but I do not know how to place x's and y's into a vector.

Comment: I mean for example, are these always e.g. $7\times 3$ matrices in the third case?

Comment: @J.M.: No. What I gave is an example. Matrix dimension and number of x's and y's z's and their positions are changing. Once I learn how to do it with an example, I thought I can adjust my original matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [`DiagonalMatrix`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiagonalMatrix.html) + [`ArrayFlatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html)

```
ClearAll[ttm]
ttm = 1 + ArrayFlatten @ ReplaceAll[i_Integer?Positive :> Transpose @ {#[[i]]}] @
      DiagonalMatrix @ Range @ Length @ # &
```

***Examples:***

```
ttm[{{x, x, x}, {y, y, y}, {z, z, z}}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
ttm[{{x, x, x}, {y, y}, {z, z, z}}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
ttm[{{x1, x3}, {y1, y2}, {z1, z2, z3}}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: @Tugrul, if the input lists are not too large, this approach seems more _"readable"_ than the ``SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix`` method. For large inputs `SparseBlockMatrix` is much faster.

Answer (score 3):

I am still not sure of what the OP wants, so here is my best guess at the intent:

```
tugrul[l : {__?VectorQ}] := With[{fl = Flatten[l]}, 
       Normal[SparseArray[Thread[Flatten[MapIndexed[PadRight[Transpose[{#}],
                                                    {Automatic, 2}, #2] &,
                                         TakeList[Range[Length[fl]], Length /@ l]], 1] ->
                                 1 + fl], Automatic, 1]]]
```

For example:

```
tugrul[{{x, x, x}, {y, y}, {z, z, z}}]
   {{1 + x, 1, 1}, {1 + x, 1, 1}, {1 + x, 1, 1}, {1, 1 + y, 1}, {1, 1 + y, 1},
    {1, 1, 1 + z}, {1, 1, 1 + z}, {1, 1, 1 + z}}

tugrul[{{x1, x3}, {y1, y2}, {z1, z2, z3}}]
   {{1 + x1, 1, 1}, {1 + x3, 1, 1}, {1, 1 + y1, 1}, {1, 1 + y2, 1},
    {1, 1, 1 + z1}, {1, 1, 1 + z2}, {1, 1, 1 + z3}}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[sA]
sA = 1 + SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix @ MapIndexed[#2[[{1, 1}]]-> Transpose@{#}&] @ # &
```

***Examples:***

```
sA @ {{x, x, x}, {y, y, y}, {z, z, z}} // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
sA @ {{x, x, x}, {y, y}, {z, z, z}} // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
sA @ {{x1, x3}, {y1, y2}, {z1, z2, z3}} // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: It is nice. Can we automatically replace `0` with `1`?

Comment: whoops...  Updated.

Comment: It happens sometimes. In `sA` function, how do you set the size of the matrix? I suppose you use the number of `x, y, z` to set the size of the matrix `sA`?

Comment: @Tugrul, the size automatically determined by the input `list` (i..e, `{Total[Length/@list], Length@list}`).

Comment: I thought so. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example. I hope you can extend it for your needs:

```
m1 = Table[
   1 + Switch[{Ceiling[i/3], j}, {1, 1}, x, {2, 2}, y, {3, 3}, z, _, 
     0], {i, 9}, {j, 3}];

m2 = Delete[m1, 4];

m3 = Table[
   1 + Switch[{Ceiling[i/3], j}, {1, 1}, 
     Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]], {2, 2}, 
     Symbol["y" <> ToString[i - 3]], {3, 3}, 
     Symbol["z" <> ToString[i - 6]], _, 0], {i, 9}, {j, 3}];
m3 = Delete[m2, {{2}, {6}}];

m1//MatrixForm
m2//MatrixForm
m3//MatrixForm
```

[image]